# Count a MongoDB collection with a query which should ignore the case sensitive

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

I have the collection with the name "student_collection" and this collection has the following fields.

```
1) _id   2) user_name 3) first_name  4) last_name
```

with the following values.

```
ObjectId("5996e8308a4931d0e910cd2d")      testuser      Test       User
ObjectId("5996fa9c8a4931d0e910cd31")      devuser       Dev        User
```

I am trying to get the user count with the unique field "user_name". If I gave the below request, I got the correct count.

```
var query = BSONDocument("user_name" -> "testuser")

val count = collection.db.command(
      Count(
        collection.name,
        Some(query)
      )
)
```

How do I get the count of the collection with a query which should ignore the case sensitive?

For example,

```
var query = BSONDocument("user_name" -> "TestUser")
```

I am using the below versions:

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8" 
"org.reactivemongo" %% "reactivemongo" % "0.11.14"
```

Comment: It depends on the MongoDB version at the server and the underlying driver version in use. Modern MongoDB versions have the ability to define case insensitve options on indexes and subsequent query operations. Without support of a recent version and driver, you use regular expressions, which invoke a full collection scan.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you. I have updated the reactivemongo, scala versions and used MongoDB driver in my question.

Comment: It's mostly about the actual server version, as well as having a recent enough driver release to issue the required options. But the "server" is the important thing, and you need MongoDB 3.4 at the very least.

Comment: Yes. The server version v3.4.6.

Comment: Also no need to define query as `var`, and rather use the convenient `collection.count(query)`

Answer (score 0):

@Neil Lunn Thanks for your suggestion. BSONRegex is working.

```
var query = BSONDocument("user_name" -> BSONRegex("^" + "TestUser", "i"))
```